# Comment traduire « attorney » et « lawyer » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, droit-et-justice

Je voulais savoir s'il y avait une différence entre un *attorney* et un *lawyer* en français. Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre la différence en anglais.

Est-ce que pour les deux on dit qu'ils sont des avocats ? Y a-t-il un mot pour chacun ?

Comment: [This](http://m.courierjournal.net/columnists/ask_the_attorney/article_03c330c4-e02a-11e2-84fa-0019bb2963f4.html?mode=jqm) might help explain the difference in English, at least (and add a third English term (counselor at law) to the confusion).

Comment: I’ll leave the vocabulary aspect of your question to a French native, but it’s important to note that a “Notaire” in France, Quebec, & most “civil-law/aka Romano-Germanic law” countries “[may be roughly described as a **lawyer** who specializes in the law relating to real estate, sales, mortgages, and the settlement of estates but who is not allowed to appear in court.](http://www.britannica.com/topic/notary)” So although not a lawyer in the full “avocat” sense of the French word, a civil-law “notaire” is much more similar to an American lawyer/attorney than to an American “notary public.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Attorney** réfère à une personne qui en représentent une autre, qui parle pour elle afin de donner une réponse plus adéquate. C'est un représentant.

**Lawyer** réfère à un avocat. Il conseille et défend une personne en justice, lui cite ses droits, lui dit quoi dire. Un avocat peut être un représentant.

Comment: +1, car c'est vrai que "attorney" tout seul est ambigüe car il peut vouloir dire “attorney-in-fact” et, comme vous dites, ne s’agit pas forcement d’avocat, même si l’on pense, faussement, que sans le « in-fact » on parle sans exception et uniquement d’un « lawyer et donc d’un avocat.   Cependant, avec l’ajout de « at-law », ‘attorney-at-law’ veut dire “lawyer” et donc, avocat.

Answer (score 5):

Dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14692) on traite brièvement de la différence entre la *profession* d'une part et les rôles et fonctions d'un [*mandataire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mandataire), qui pourrait être [avocat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avocat), d'autre part. Une explication en français du sens de mots anglais est hors sujet<sup>1</sup>.

En résumé, l'*attorney* Américain est un *avocat*. Plus généralement aussi ce peut être quelqu'un qui agit comme *mandataire*. Le [*power of attorney*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/power-of-attorney) est rendu par l'idée de *procuration* en français. On peut ainsi constater le lien entre la [*procuration*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/procuration) et le contrat de [*mandat*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mandat); la première étant souvent associée à l'écrit qui constate le deuxième. Le terme [*représentant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repr%C3%A9sentant) et l'idée de représentation peuvent servir à [décrire](https://nimbus.mcgill.ca/pld-ddp/dictionary/show/16739?source=OBLEN) de manière usuelle un pouvoir/rôle du [mandataire](https://nimbus.mcgill.ca/pld-ddp/dictionary/show/21166?source=OBLFR), de l'avocat, du notaire, ou être rattachés à plusieurs [autres sens](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=repr%C3%A9sentant) spécialisés (dont l'*intermédiaire*, le *courtier*, le *fiduciaire*, ou même communément le *vendeur* etc.). Mais il n'est pas à mon avis le terme à préférer pour rendre usuellement l'*attorney*. L'expression *représentant juridique*, reliée, est quant à elle peu usitée et fait aussi appel au concept d'[*agency*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=agency&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) en *common law*, réalisé par mandataire en français.<sup>2</sup>

---

Le terme ***avocat*** sert souvent de traduction autant à *lawyer* qu'à *attorney*; il est compris de tous<sup>3</sup> et désigne le juriste inscrit au tableau de son ordre professionnel, qu'il plaide ou non devant le tribunal. On lui confie différents mandats, dont le conseil, ou l'assistance et la représentation de son client devant les tribunaux. Selon le ressort et la nature des gestes à poser en contexte, on pourrait préférer [traduire](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=500716) *lawyer* par « *avocat », « avocat ou notaire* » ou par « notaire » uniquement (Québec, voir *Loi sur le notariat*, [art. 10-11, 15-16](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/N-3); France, [formation](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006062113&dateTexte=20150813), [2 nov. 1945](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=C7AF885C331565AE66425BCD18FD92BB.tpdila07v_3?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000699572&categorieLien=cid); ne pas confondre avec le [*notaire public*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=NOTAIRE) en *common law*). Des termes comme [*avocat-conseil*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=AVOCAT%20CONSEIL) ou *avocat plaidant* peuvent aider à cerner les orientations de sa pratique (et à étayer la nuance entre le *barrister* et le *solicitor*, par exemple; *Furetière* disait avocat *plaidant*, *écoutant* ou *consultant*, 1690 DHLF/Rey). Autrement on a aussi généralement le ***mandataire*** qui exécute le mandat qui lui est confié : plusieurs réalités s'expriment par le biais du mandat et les termes qui les décrivent varient selon l'institution juridique. Par ailleurs, si ce mandat impliquait ne serait-ce que la suggestion par le mandataire d'entreprendre des poursuites judiciaires, ou la rédaction d'une [requête](http://www.ouest-france.fr/il-redigeait-des-actes-reserves-aux-avocats-1062957) ou encore la représentation devant un tribunal en matières contentieuses, entre autres, alors ce mandataire devra être avocat pour pouvoir l'accomplir (par exemple au Québec, voir *Loi sur le Barreau* [art. 128](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/B-1); France, [art. 154](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006078311), RIN [art. 6](http://legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000465456&dateTexte=&categorieLien=id)) puisqu'il s'agit souvent d'actes réservés qui sont du ressort exclusif de ce juriste, la profession étant [réglementée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocat_en_France).

---

<sub>1. Voir sur [*ELL*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=lawyer)/[*ELU*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=lawyer). Mais une note au sujet des termes anglais : aux *É.-U.*, un *attorney* ([1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attorney), [2](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/attorney), [3](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/attorney), [4](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/attorney)) sans autre précision que l'idée du professionnel, c'est presque toujours un *avocat* de pratique privée. Le terme *attorney* pourrait aussi signifier [*attorney-in-fact*](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/attorney-in-fact) dans certaines situations plus usuelles de mandat où quelqu'un agit par procuration spécifiquement ou généralement, ou représente quelqu'un d'autre qui agit par son entremise; il ne s'agit pas nécessairement d'un avocat dans ce cas. Mais sans contexte ni information sur l'origine ni à qui on destine la traduction, on ne peut faire un choix éclairé. En *Angleterre*, on a déjà eu l'*attorney*, mais on a aboli ce terme qui avait des connotations [négatives](https://www.etymonline.com/word/attorney) pour le remplacer par l’appellation *solicitor* suite au [*Judicature Act*](https://archive.org/stream/supremecourtofju00wils#page/108/mode/2up) de 1873 (voir art. 87; 100 ans après l'indépendance des É.-U.); ça s'oppose traditionnellement au [*barrister*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/barrister)([ety.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/barrister)), celui qui plaide la cause à la [barre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barre) du tribunal. Ce sont des différences d'emploi entre l'anglais américain et britannique qu'il faut saisir pour ensuite pouvoir les rendre en français.</sub>

<sub>2. Il n'y a pas adéquation entre les concepts de droit anglais et ceux du droit civil, mais il ne faudrait pas en déduire que des termes tels [*procureur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/procureur?idf=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYpoXbic;str=0), [*solliciteur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/solliciteur?idf=dmfXgXrmXsegg;str=0), [*solicitor*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/solicitor) et même [*atourné*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/atourner?idf=dmfXdXpcYadff;str=0) n'existent pas en français ou qu'ils n'aient été utilisés hier ou aujourd'hui pour décrire différentes fonctions proches de celles de l'avocat. Le contexte *canadien* en est une illustration; on traduit les termes *counsel*, *legal counsel*, *lawyer* et *attorney* par *avocat* ou *conseiller juridique* ([fiche 1](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=attorney&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0); on lira avec intérêt toutes les observations de toutes les entrées). On utilise aussi le terme *procureur* pour rendre le *solicitor* ([fiche 5](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=procureur&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0)), mais aussi pour rendre l'*attorney*, et différemment, avec le (substitut du) [*procureur général*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=procureur&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) et le [*procureur de la couronne*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=CROWN%20PROSECUTOR) (ces derniers concepts très proches de ceux du *State/Distict Attorney* et de l'*Attorney General* aux É.-U., généralement des avocats qui représente l'État et relèvent de la fonction publique). Au Canada on a déjà eu le [*Solliciteur général*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solliciteur_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral_du_Canada), une institution britannique. Au *Québec* la [*Loi sur le Barreau*](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/B-1) dispose à l'article 1e : "«avocat», «conseiller juridique», «membre du Barreau», «procureur»: quiconque est inscrit au Tableau;". Seuls ces juristes peuvent se prévaloir de ces titres.</sub>

<sub>3. Il faut noter que l'emploi du terme *procureur* pour désigner un avocat de pratique privée est [*vieilli*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/procureur) en France (voir aussi [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/procureur/64108?q=procureur#754956), [*GDT*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8370002)); il est périlleux de l'utiliser. En effet, le *procureur* est en France un magistrat depuis 1256 (*DHLF/Rey*). Le [*Procureur de la République*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procureur_de_la_R%C3%A9publique_%28France%29), les *procureurs généraux*, leurs *substituts*, ainsi que les *avocats généraux* sont **tous** des magistrats en France. Autrement dit aucun d'entre eux n'est avocat; leur charge est incompatible avec celle de l'avocat qu'ils ne peuvent cumuler. Contrairement à l'Amérique du Nord où les juges sont presque tous issus de la pratique privée, en France on est directement formé comme magistrat à l'[*École nationale de la magistrature*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_nationale_de_la_magistrature). Un [magistrat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magistrat_(France)) du *parquet* ne bénéficie cependant pas de la garantie d'inamovibilité dont bénéficie celui du *siège*.</sub>

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks! After reading the link I included I fully understood what you referred to; it is not a presumption/fiction/construction like I thought, as it is based on a writing. I had never heard this idea phrased like so, so I'm thankful for the insight. I hope the edit will be to your satisfaction. Cheers!